React Native Firestore useEffect Fetch Issue with where Clause and Pagination
I am working on a React Native project that uses Firestore to fetch a list of services. I am trying to fetch services with a price greater than or equal to 70 and implement pagination using Firestore's startAfter method. However, I am encountering an error when fetching more data.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { FlashList } from "@shopify/flash-list"; 

const PAGE_SIZE = 10;

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loadingMore, setLoadingMore] = useState(false);
  const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchServices(true);
  }, []);

  const fetchServices = async (initial = false) => {
    if (!initial && (loadingMore || !lastVisible)) return;

    initial ? setLoading(true) : setLoadingMore(true);

    try {
      let query = firestore().collection("services").where("price", ">=", 70);

      if (!initial && lastVisible) {
        query = query.startAfter(lastVisible);
      }

      query = query.limit(PAGE_SIZE);

      const servicesCollection = await query.get();
      const servicesList = servicesCollection.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      setServices((prevServices) =>
        initial ? servicesList : [...prevServices, ...servicesList]
      );
      setLastVisible(
        servicesCollection.docs[servicesCollection.docs.length - 1]
      );
      console.log(servicesCollection.docs[servicesCollection.docs.length - 1]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching services: ", error);
    } finally {
      initial ? setLoading(false) : setLoadingMore(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FlashList
      data={services}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      estimatedItemSize={200}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      onEndReached={() => fetchServices(false)}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      ListFooterComponent={<RenderLoading />}
    />
  );
};


Error fetching services: [Error: [firestore/invalid-argument] Client
specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from
failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are
problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid
field name).]


The initial fetch works correctly, but when fetchServices(false) in FlashList is
called, the error occurs.
I have two documents with a price field in    my Firestore
collection.
Removing the .where("price", ">=", 70)    clause eliminates the error
but returns all documents instead of    filtering by price.

What I've Tried:

Verified that the price field exists in all documents and is a valid
number.

Checked the Firestore rules and indexes.


Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
